# android studio hang frequently on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, freeze

I have switched to ubuntu 14.04 from windows7 and now my android studio is hanging too much and my system configuration is as follow :
Ram : 6 GB
Processor : Dual core

Main problem is while debugging the application and for that i am using device not an emulator and i have also seen that my sdk size is 60 GB on ubuntu but on window it was about 15-18 Gb and I don't understand why it is taking this much space?

So if someone has idea why this problem is coming,
Please Help me with it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The hanging problem can be a result of lot of different things:

-It might be because your Android Studio is using too much of RAM.
You can check this by following command:

```
$top -o %MEM
```

this would result in such an output:

[the output of top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLmlv.png)

the "Java" there in the first line, in the linked image is the Android Studio and in my case its using 47.5% of RAM. 
As I have low RAM, the OS starts using SWAP memory which would make the application respond slower. Usage of swap memory can checked by using command

```
$vmstat 1
```

So, there is no way you can bring that down. You can only close other applications so as to provide the required RAM.
I have 2Gigs of RAM and therefore I login into **OpenBox** and then start Android Studio, this works for me quite well

While the size of SDK must not be a problem.
The size of SDK depends upon the tools and the API related SDKs that you have downloaded.

You can open up your SDK manager and delete some packages if you want but that wont make Android Studio run faster.

-The other reason can be the iBus-daemon and that is a known issue. The workarounds can be found here 
http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus